# Select only latest record for every employees and for specific employee in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL DB and in it there's a table with activity logs of employees.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| log_id | employee_id | date_time  | action_type |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|   1    |      1      | 2015/02/03 |   action1   |
|   2    |      2      | 2015/02/01 |   action1   |
|   3    |      2      | 2017/01/02 |   action2   |
|   4    |      3      | 2016/02/12 |   action1   |
|   5    |      1      | 2016/10/12 |   action2   |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

And I would need 2 queries. First, to get for every employee his last action. So from this example table I would need to get row 3,4 and 5 with all columns. And second, get the latest action only for specified employee.

Any ideas how to achieve this? I'm using Spring Data JPA, but raw SQL Query would be also great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: select * from table where [date-time] in (select Max(date_time) from table  where employee_id=1 );  this would give you latest action for a specific employee and you can run a loo may be foreach employee changing the employee Id in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ready for a fred ed...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT employee_id
            , MAX(date_time) date_time 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY employee_id
     ) y 
    ON y.employee_id = x.employee_id 
   AND y.date_time = x.date_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected output by doing a self join

```
select a.*
from demo a
left join demo b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id 
and a.date_time < b.date_time
where b.employee_id is null
```

Note it may return multiple rows for single employee if there are rows with same date_time you might need a CASE statement and another attribute to decide which row should be picked to handle this kind of situation

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27b178/1)

Comment: I find @Strawberry's answer way more efficient for large tables.

Answer (score 0):

For your first query. Simply

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tableName t1
WHERE t1.log_id = (SELECT MAX(t2.log_id)
                 FROM tableName t2
                 WHERE t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id)
```

For the second one

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tableName  t1
WHERE t1.employee_id=X and t1.log_id = (SELECT MAX(t2.log_id)
                 FROM tableName t2
                 WHERE t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id);
```

Comment: Query #1 - I find @Strawberry's answer way more efficient for large tables.